# DOSBOX In Ubuntu: Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, turbo-c, dosbox

My operating system is **Ubuntu** and i am using **Turbo C** in **DOSBOX**.

This is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, k;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(k=1;k<(i*2);k++)
    {
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

after saving this program. When I am compile my programme using (ALT+F9)

it gives me error

> Unable to open include file 'STDIO.H'

so tell me how to set path for **ubuntu DosBox**

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, there are many nice development environments that will allow you to use modern C.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But i only want to use Turbo c. @JoachimPileborg

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: Do a favour on yourself, do not use Turbo C++.